# USQL query for SELECTING a range from a table

Tags: u-sql

Data is as

```
    index id
        1 112
        1 112
        2 109
        2 109
        3 125
        3 125
        4 199
        4 199
        5 100
        5 100
```

The id are not incremental but are sequential in nature take it as a GUID that's why i have assigned index for Range query

The user will give @startid @endid and i will get the rows for this range

Now first i get the index corresponding these id like

```
@indexes = SELECT DISTINCT index 
 FROM @table 
WHERE id IN (@startid, endid);
```

as a result i get (let's say for example if @startid = 2 and @endid = 4)

```
2
4
```

Now i know the Range will be BETWEEN 2 and 4 i.e. i want rows corresponding 2,3 and 4

```
@result= SELECT index AS index,
         id AS id 
         FROM @data
         WHERE 
         index BETWEEN (THE TWO ENTRIES FROM @indexes)
```

would have done this using Nested SELECT but USQL doesn't  support it.

now is there a way to treat @indexes as a list and specify range or something???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BETWEEN` is supported in U-SQL, it's just case-sensitive, eg

```
DECLARE CONST @startId int = 2;
DECLARE CONST @endId int = 4;


@input = SELECT *
     FROM (
        VALUES
        ( 1, 112 ),
        ( 1, 112 ),
        ( 2, 109 ),
        ( 2, 109 ),
        ( 3, 125 ),
        ( 3, 125 ),
        ( 4, 199 ),
        ( 4, 199 ),
        ( 5, 100 ),
        ( 5, 100 )
    ) AS x ( index, id );


@output =
    SELECT *
    FROM @input
    WHERE index BETWEEN @startId AND @endId;


OUTPUT @output TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting:false);
```

My results:

[image: My Results]

Alternative approach:

```
    DECLARE CONST @startId int = 109;
    DECLARE CONST @endId int = 199;


    @input = SELECT *
         FROM (
            VALUES
            ( 1, 112 ),
            ( 1, 112 ),
            ( 2, 109 ),
            ( 2, 109 ),
            ( 3, 125 ),
            ( 3, 125 ),
            ( 4, 199 ),
            ( 4, 199 ),
            ( 5, 100 ),
            ( 5, 100 )
        ) AS x ( index, id );


@output =
    SELECT i. *
    FROM @input AS i
         CROSS JOIN
         (
         SELECT MIN(index) AS minIndex,
                MAX(index) AS maxIndex
         FROM @input AS i
         WHERE id IN ( @startId, @endId )
               ) AS x
    WHERE i.index BETWEEN x.minIndex AND x.maxIndex;    

    OUTPUT @output TO "/output/output.csv"
    USING Outputters.Csv(quoting:false);
```

Comment: well that doesn't answer my question, i already know that between is supported in U-SQL and want to use the same approach or any alternative to do this.

in your answer you have declared the start and end index, however in my case the index are in @indexes that resulted as a query on the same table. i hope you get what i'm trying to say here

Comment: startid and endid is the guid then we will calculate indexes(start and end) on the basis of these guid and then we have to use that indexes for the final query.

Comment: I've added an alternate approach to my answer - is that what you're looking for?  It's not that clear to me from your description but have a look at my second answer, see if that helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm mate.

i have one last question for the sake of understanding it. 

After doing the cross join and then using BETWEEN why we're not getting (no. of resultant rows)*2 *duplicate entries* due to the Cartesian product ? does Between by pass this behavior.

Comment: Yes BETWEEN is acting like a join between the two tables.